# I am Scraping multiple web pages which gives the same results as the first page in Python selenium. What would be the reason?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am scraping goodreads.com using Selenium and Beautiful soup. I can able to get the results for the first page. When I give the URL for the second page then it loads the first page and gives the first page results only. I tried with different pages and all loads the first page only. What would be the reason and how to overcome this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import time
import re
import requests
from itertools import zip_longest
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# First-page site URL: https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/business?page=1

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
# Reading the second page
driver.get("https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/non-fiction?page=2")
time.sleep(3)

summaryItems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'bookTitle')]")
job_links = [summaryItem.get_attribute("href") for summaryItem in summaryItems]


for job_link in job_links:
    driver.get(job_link)

    #Closing the pop-up window
    try:
        close = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('gr-iconButton')
        close.click()

    except:

        close = "None"
    try:
        # Taking book description
        more = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#description > a:nth-child(3)").click()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        #for item in soup.findAll("span", id=re.compile("^freeText"))[:2]:
        #    print(item.text)
        sections = soup.findAll("span", id=re.compile("^freeText"))[:2]
        print("message ")
        i = 0
        for item in soup.findAll("span", id=re.compile("^freeText"))[:2]:
            i = i+1
            if i == 2:
                desc.append(item.text)

    except:

        more = "None"

    try: # Taking book title
               # time.sleep(2)
        job_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[@class='gr-h1 gr-h1--serif']").text
                #job_title = driver.find_element_by_id('bookTitle').find_element_by_class_name('gr-h1 gr-h1--serif').text
        title.append(job_title)
                #print(title)

    except:
        job_title = "None"

        #Taking Author name

    try:
               # time.sleep(2)
        authors = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='authorName']").text
        author.append(authors)
                    #print(author)

    except:
        authors = "None"

        #Taking Ratings

    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    rate = soup.find("span", itemprop="ratingValue").text.strip()
    rates = rate.replace('\n','')

    rating.append(rates)


driver.close()
```

Output:

I am able to scrape book title, author name, book description, and rating for the first page only.

Comment: What's your initial value of rating, author, desc (the vars where you append)?

Comment: @Yun The rating is 4.08, author: Eric Ries, Desc = book description. this is for one record

Comment: @Yun Did I answer your question correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should login first to scrap data on other page.

Try to add following code into your script:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# Add below code after webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.goodreads.com/user/sign_in")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#user_email").send_keys("your email")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#user_password").send_keys("your password")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='Sign in']").click()
```